# Which types can you pass between Scala and Pyspark inside Zeppelin?

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I use Zeppelin 0.7.1 and sometimes I would like to pass non distributed data types like Seq or Array. Currently I always convert them to Dataset and get them in Python as dataframe. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple type using z ZeppelinContext is very convenient.

**In Spark**

```
z.put("name", "zeppelin")
z.put("array", Array(1, 2, 3))
```

**In PySpark**

```
%pyspark
z.get("name")
ar = z.get("array")
print(ar[0])

z.put("pyspark", "cool")
z.put("pyarray", [1, 2, 3])
```

**In Spark again**

```
z.get("pyspark")
val ar = z.get("pyarray").asInstanceOf[java.util.ArrayList[Int]]
```

> For complex types, can add serialize to string on one side and deserialize on the other side.

Comment: But I ask about things like let's say array of case classes (or tuples).
I have the data which are already stored on master and I want to plot them inside Python and I don't want unnecessarily shuffle them around.

Comment: Now we're getting closer to the answer to my question :)
Just as I already said I have the array inside Scala and I want to pass it to Python so I want to do the opposite of your example and I don't know any elegant way of doing that.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. The example already includes pass array from Scala to Python and from Python back to Scala.

Comment: Sorry you are right :)
Thank you for your answer :)